# Problemas al conectarme con sqlserver usando entityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Tengo un proyecto que recien empece con entityframework6 en modo code first hice mis pocos y genere las tablas  pero al intentar  correr las pruebas unitarias entityframework intenta conectarse localmente en lugar de ir a donde le estoy especificando con mi  clase de contextexto adjunto la info de mi web config :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TMS" connectionString="Password=PWD;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USERID;Initial Catalog=TMSDB;Data Source=MYIP"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Miclase de contexto:

```
public class FSContext : DbContext
    {
        public FSContext() : base("TMS")
        {


        }

        public FSContext(string nameOfConnectionString) : base(nameOfConnectionString)
        {


        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Shipping>().ToTable("FSShippings");

            //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
        public DbSet<Shipping> Shippings { get; set; }
    }
```

Lo que estoy haciendo para instanciarla.

```
FSContext context = new FSContext(“TMS”);
```

Comment: Se me quedo el webcinfig:

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TMS" connectionString="Password=PWD;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USERID;Initial Catalog=TMSDB;Data Source=MYIP"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

Comment: En lugar de añadirlo como comentario, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/76655/edit) tu pregunta y añádelo

Comment: Ayudaría también si agregaras el texto del mensaje de error.

Answer (score 0):

dejalo solo asi:

```
public class FSContext : DbContext
{
    public FSContext() : base("TMS")
    {


    }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Shipping>().ToTable("FSShippings");

        //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    public DbSet<Shipping> Shippings { get; set; }
}
```

y en tu cadena de conexión debes tener algo como esto:

```
  <connectionStrings>
        <add name="TMS" connectionString="Data Source=NombreServer;Initial Catalog=TMSDB;User ID=sa;Password=PWD;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  </connectionStrings>
```